# Histogram using Matplotlib with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, matplotlib, histogram

I've been trying to use matplotLib to basically make a histogram of pixels using the image the user selects. The user select part of the image using JCROP and then when he/she his the submit button, The PlotsHandlers, post methods gets the parameters. I then crop it and try to just display the histogram using [method described here](http://gae-matplotlib-demo.appspot.com/) to plot it. I'm testing by deploying it but it just doens't work. Can someone guide me as to how to plot histograms(or any other data) using matplotlib in GAE.

```
import os
import webapp2
import re
import jinja2
import Image
import ImageOps
import logging
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env= jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)
PAGE_RE = r'(/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)'


def render_str(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

#Opens the image and Grayscales it
def openAndGrayScaleImage(imageLocationString):
    OpenedImage = Image.open(imageLocationString)
    return ImageOps.grayscale(OpenedImage)

def cropImage(image, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    box = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
    return image.crop(box)  



class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(render_str(template, **kw))

    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)


class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("mainPage.html")

class PlotsHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('/')



def post(self):
        image1 = openAndGrayScaleImage("images.jpg")
        #Parameters for cropping. Verified that it's working
            x1 = int(self.request.get('x1'))
        y1 = int(self.request.get('y1'))
        x2 = int(self.request.get('x2'))
        y2 = int(self.request.get('y2'))
        image2 = cropImage(image1, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        #Get the sequence of pixels
            values_= list(image2.getdata())
        n, bins, patches = plt.hist(values_, 256/2, normed=1, facecolor ='blue', alpha = .75)
        plt.xlabel('Light Intensity')
        plt.ylabel('Probability')
        plt.title('Normalized distribution of light')
        plt.axis([0, 255, 0, .3])
        plt.grid(True)
        rv = StringIO.StringIO()
        plt.savefig(rv, format = "png")
        imgb64 = rv.getvalue().encode("base64").strip()
        plt.clf()
        rv.close()
        self.response.write("""<html><body>""")
        self.response.write("<img src='data:image/png;base64,%s'/>" % img_b64)
        self.response.write("""</body> </html>""")







app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                                ('/plots', PlotsHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. Forgot to set threadsafe to false in app.yaml.

Comment: Matplotlib uses threads(I know for a fact that Image processing, which is what I needed matplotlib for, requires a lot of threadwork). In addition, if you visit the bottom of the [third part libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27), it tells you to set the threadsafe value to false.